Cookie-Problem with Google Search widget and JavaScript/php
I am setting a cookie with javascript
document.cookie = "acceptCookies=1; expires=" + new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)).toUTCString() + "; path=/; SameSite=Strict";

And it works just fine, but not when I open the site using the google search widget in android. In that case the cookie is lost every time I reopen it. SameSite=Lax has the same effect.
So I tried to reset it with php like this.
    if ($_COOKIE['acceptCookies'] != "2"){
        setcookie("acceptCookies", "2", ['expires' => time() + 3600*24*365, 'path' => '/', 'samesite' => 'Strict' ]);
    }

But the problem is not solved. Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

I'm not aware of what that widget does; but it sounds like it doesn't open the page in a real local browser, but only in some sort of webview - in which cookies might be restricted? "In that case the cookie is lost every time I reopen it." - are you sure it was even accepted in the first place? Logging the value of document.cookie would show it as existing?

Thanks - at least the cookie is saved as long as the 'browser' is open. But the next time it is gone..
